# Let $A\in M_n$, and $A=0$. What is $\dim(\ker(A))=$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$, and $A=0$.

What is $\dim(\ker(A))=$?

Answer (score 3):

It is $n$ since every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ lies in $\ker(A)$.